# images and selection list javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have these products that I would like to make appear on my website.I want the images to appear when they are selected in the selection list. so when I pick "boots" an image of boots will appear on my website. I think if I set the images to hidden in the html and then if it is selected that specific image becomes unhidden using a if statement in javascript. any help I cant seem to get the javascript working. thanks.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="product1">
    <img src="Jersey.jpg" style="visibility:hidden;" />
</div>

<div id="product2">
    <img src="boots.png" style="visibility:hidden;" />
</div>

<td class="inputcell">
      <select name="prod" id="prod">
          <option id="product1" value="0">Products from Sports World</option>
          <option id="product2" value="50.00">Jersey ($50.00)</option>
          <option id="product1" value="45.50">Boots ($45.50)</option>   
      </select>
</td>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) 
{
    if (products[i].id == selected_id){

    }
}
```

Comment: you did not provide valid or complete code.

Comment: IDs need to be unique in HTML. Where is the "selection list"? How are things "selected"

Comment: please create a fiddle.

Comment: you img tags are wrong, they should be `<img src="boots.png" style="visibility:hidden;" />`

Comment: sorry but im new to this whtas a fiddle?

Comment: @user3091082 A example hosted on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: never use inline styles never use an id for more than one element never use visibility hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
$('select option').click(function () { // on a click on option..
   if($(this).val() == '50.00') { // jersey selected
     $('.jersey').show();
   } else if($(this).val() == '50.00') {
     $('.boots').show(); // hide images on your own! :) 
   }
}
```

And also, change these:

```
<img src="boots.png" style="visibility:hidden; img/>
```

To these:

```
<img src="boots.png" class="boots" style="display: none;"/>
```

Similar thing for the jersey image, to make sure it gets visible once the correct option is selected!

Comment: is this using jquery ? do I need to put the function in a script ? thanks for the help much appricated

Comment: Yes this is jQuery and you need to put it inside `script` tag! :)

Comment: that's what I thought thanks. I put it in a script tag and it doesn't seem to work. also would I be able to put the jquery in a .js file and link it to my html ? again thnks so much

Comment: Yes it will work. How doesn't it work? Are you having jQuery attached to your page?

Answer (score 0):

## problem one... IDS ARE unique. they are supposed to be attached to one element and one element only.

problem two im not suer where you get "products.length"

three
`<img src="boots.png" id='boots' class='catimg'/>`

do not use inline styles ever

apply an id to the other image as well as well as the class of catimg. then you should apply name attributes to your list items

```
$("#myselect").on("change",function(){
 var name = $(this).val();
   if(!$(this).hasClass("active")){
      $('.active').hide(0).removeClass('active');
      $("#" + name).show(0).addClass("active");
  }

 })
```